# How do I get the password knowing part of it and the length

Tags: passwords, hash

I'm new to all this, I'm trying to use [Hash Suite](http://hashsuite.openwall.net/) to find a password with a word + 2 numbers. I know what the word is but not the numbers but I also know the length of the passwords ... What do I have to do?

Comment: run a script to permute the numbers and pass each entry to the hash program

Comment: The easiest way will be to write a small program to do it. What programming languages do you know? What data do you have about the password, I assume the hashed value? Do you know which hash algorithm was used?

Comment: let's assume that the word is "Subrosa" the password lacks only two numbers ( 3 maxium ) ... how do I write the small program ?

Comment: This last comment will make this question unsuitable for this site. "How to write a program" won't even catch attention at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really simple python script that will generate a text file with the word "Subrosa" followed by every 2 and 3 digit number. You should be able to import this wordlist file into your Hash Suite program (though I've never used it myself).

```
import itertools

knownWord = "Subrosa"    # replace this with the word you know

f=open('./wordlist.txt', 'w+')

# try 2 digit numbers
res = itertools.product('1234567890', 2) 
for i in res: 
   f.write( knowWord.join(i) + "\n" )

# try 3 digit numbers
res = itertools.product('1234567890', 3) 
for i in res: 
   f.write( knowWord.join(i) + "\n" )
```

(disclaimer: I'm at work and don't have python installed here, so I can't check that this works, I'll make this a community wiki so that others can fix it if it's broken.)